# why is the <?php wp_head ?> tag creating a top margin at the top of my theme header

Tags: wordpress

Hey people, I've been coming here for a while but just decided to join.

I'm new to php and I'm trying to make a website with WordPress as the CMS.

Anyway, I'm basically making my own theme because I don't want my website to look like a blog, and it's going pretty smoothly so far but theres this huge top margin gap in the browser even when I set margins to 0px.

I tried trial and error and found out that it's being caused by: `<?php  wp_head();  ?>`

Comment: "I'm basically making my own theme because I don't want my website to look like a blog" - I laud your DIY efforts but just FYI there are many, many themes for wordpress that don't look like a web blog. Here are some examples: http://woothemes.com and http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/ . Search for "wordpress premium themes"

Comment: Please also see my [expanded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15597419/414385) apparently too "radical of a change" answer to @ariefbayu's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's two different things.

### 1. `wp_head()` function

`wp_head()` is a template tag to print whatever plugin / theme specific function used by wordpress action. [Read codex for more detail about it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head).

### 2. The admin bar

The top margin, is generated by wordpress's admin bar.

To fix this for logged in users you can do a couple of things:

#### Disable admin bar from the admin:

1. Go to admin panel
2. Users >> User Profile
3. Uncheck 'when viewing
   site' on 'Show Admin Bar'

#### Remove the admin bar from your theme entirely:

1. Open your `functions.php`
2. Add this to it:

   ```
   function my_function_admin_bar(){ return false; }
   add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
   ```

#### Remove only the code which creates the css:

1. Open your `functions.php`
2. Add this to it:

   ```
   function my_filter_head() { remove_action('wp_head', '_admin_bar_bump_cb'); }
   add_action('get_header', 'my_filter_head');
   ```

Note: Extensive updates are from [@hitautodestruct](https://stackoverflow.com/users/414385/hitautodestruct)

Comment: thanks this worked great, but will users of my them encounter the same issue?

Comment: only if they enable admin bar. But, you could always add warning notice to your downloader about this potential problem.

Comment: @tanktery You should be seeing the top margin only if you are logged in. Have a look at your site on chrome incognito mode (ctrl+shift+n) or firefox private mode (ctrl+shift+p).

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I expanded the answer and did not re write it. Another answer would have probably been missed when there is already a checked answer. I don't think I "overcorrected" anything. Most posts on SO are not marked as 'community wikis' and the whole point of SO is to improve answers. Also, maybe you should ask the user how he feels about my edit?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks, I didn't realize you were saying that as an alternative to my edit. I can see that who ever rejected my edit clearly did not read through as the comments state that 'It has changed to much of the answer'.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Not sure if you saw my small discussion with ariefbayu, but in the end I took your advice and posted a new answer after another edit was rejected. Lo and behold ariefbayu switched his answer to mine and I deleted mine (almost like a weird edit).

Comment: @quetzalcoatl I guess leaving the discussion is pointless. I think you can remove it.

Answer (score 6):

you neeed to call wp_footer() in your footer

just insert this line `<?php wp_footer();?>` into your footer.php file

Answer (score 2):

If you have updated your wordpress install to the latest version.. there seems to be some bug with the admin bar...

were it would produce an inline stylesheet appended to the top of your pages.. causing the margin-top:28px

see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/31-update-causing-28px-top-spacing-in-html-body)

1 recomendation is to put a new function into your functions.php file located in your theme folder.. this will completly remove the bar, so no users of your theme will have any of the same issues!

```
function my_function_admin_bar(){ 
  return false; 
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
```

Not sure if this will help.. but worth a shot.. also turning off the admin bar while viewing the front end of the site under your profile page..